# opening results from curl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I did a curl on a url in my command line

```
curl http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/30/world/middleeast/30policy.html?hp
```

and I got this response

```
[1] 8742
```

I then hit enter again and got this response

```
[1]+  Done   curl http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/30/world/middleeast/30policy.html?hp
```

Is there anyway to open that file in my terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell curl to follow redirects by using -L

```
curl  -L "http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/30/world/middleeast/30policy.html?hp"
```